# Using BackgroundWorker On VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use BackGroundWorker for querying database an set new labels...here's my code:

```
Private Sub FormMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BgWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BgWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BgWorker.DoWork
Call MySqlConnect()

        Dim str As String
        str = " Select * from room "
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter(str, conn)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "room")

For i = 0 To ds.Tables("room").Rows.Count - 1
            Dim newLabel As New Label
            newLabel.Text = ds.Tables("room").Rows(i)("room_code")
            newLabel.Name = newLabel.Text
            newLabel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
            newLabel.Size = New Drawing.Size(100, 100)
            newLabel.Font = New Font("Tahoma", 15, FontStyle.Regular)
            newLabel.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter
            newLabel.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue

 Select Case i

            Case 0 To 4
                newLabel.Location = New Point(20 * i + ((i + 0.25) * newLabel.Width), 20) 
            Case 5 To 9
                newLabel.Location = New Point(20 * i + ((i - 5.75) * newLabel.Width), 140)
            Case 10 To 14
                newLabel.Location = New Point(20 * i + ((i - 11.75) * newLabel.Width), 260)
            Case 15 To 19
                newLabel.Location = New Point(20 * i + ((i - 17.75) * newLabel.Width), 380)
            Case 20 To 24
                newLabel.Location = New Point(20 * i + ((i - 23.75) * newLabel.Width), 500)
            Case 25 To 30
                newLabel.Location = New Point(20 * i + ((i - 29.75) * newLabel.Width), 620)

        End Select        

Dim ii As Integer = i
            Me.Invoke(Sub()
                      Controls.Add(newLabel)
                      If ds.Tables("room").Rows(ii)("room_status") = "1" Then
                          newLabel.BackColor = Color.LightGreen    
                      ElseIf ds.Tables("room").Rows(ii)("room_status") = "2" Then
                          newLabel.BackColor = Color.Red    
                      End If
                  End Sub)
        Next
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
End Sub

Private Sub BgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
    BgWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

The codes look goes well but the color of the labels has not change if I enter a value ....if there is something wrong with the codes or something is missing with the codes ?

Please an advice or sample code for me

Ps: I'm Using Visual Studio 2010 Express

Comment: That doesn't look like something that would take a long time.  If the query is long running, run that in the background worker, but all of that gui stuff has to happen on the main thread.  Right now, you don't need that worker.

Comment: but the labels do not change if the value in the database change at any time...how can i fix this...? any suggestions for me...?

Comment: One way would be to use a timer and constantly poll the database for those changes.  The code you have isn't close to doing something like that.

Comment: if i use a timer and constantly poll the database for Reviews those changes ... does affect the other controls such as buttons and forms ? .. because this is the main form

Comment: I don't know what affect you are talking about.  Your code doesn't check for any changes, it just grabs all the rows in room table, so it would constantly be adding duplicate labels all the time.  You also aren't setting a location for the label, so every label is sitting on top of the other label.

Comment: i'm sorry some codes are missing... :) let me edit first..